# Bootstrap classes getting repeated in React Bootstrap

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am customizing my react-bootstrap theme following the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/theming/). The customization is working fine but when I look up an element in the chrome inspector it shows the same bootstrap classes getting repeated multiple times.
For example, if I am using the bootstrap's `.btn` class for my button, then the `.btn` class will repeat and override itself multiple times. 
My question is whether it will affect any performance of my app and if it does how to fix it?

Check the following picture for reference 
[image]

Comment: try to give a separate class or add a suffix or prefix to the class. Example: btn-cust

Comment: So I am worried that whether it will have any effect on my app's performance or not?